# component with imported module (highcharts) unit-test how to! vue3,vitest

Tags: highcharts, vuejs3, vitest

in my project, i'm using highcharts moudle in Mycomponent in vue3 ts and it's working well.
i'm also add unit-test code to using vitest to check this component working well.

but now i got a error message below my code, i don't know how can i access and check highchart data
i though that Mycomponent was mounted but i didn't declarer or render highchart module.

can you give me the some advice or link for check to resolve this probleme ?

thanks!

Mycomponent.vue like that

```
script setup lang="ts">

interface Config {
  name?: string
  type: string
  series: Array<any>,
  headers?: Array<any>
}

const props = defineProps<Config>()

<template>
  <highcharts :options="chartOptions"></highcharts>
</template>
```

i tried to test this component with vitest

MY spec.ts

```
const wrapper = mount(Mycomponent, {
  props : {
    series: [{ name: 'delta', data: [500, 83, -200, -800, 228, 184] }],
    type: 'column'
  },
})

describe('Mycomponent', () => {
  it('Mycomponent Highcharts', () => {

  test('Chart data type should be set correctly', () => {
    expect(wrapper.props().type).toBeTypeOf("string")
  })
```

and i got a error like that

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: highcharts
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.
  at <Mycomponent series= [ { name: 'delta', data: [ 500, 83, -200, -800, 228, 184 ] } ] type="column" ref="VTU_COMPONENT" >
  at <VTUROOT>
```

this is my main.ts

```
import HighchartsVue from 'highcharts-vue'
import Highchart from 'highcharts'

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(HighchartsVue)
app.use(Highchart)

app.mount('#app')
```

config.plugins.VueWrapper.install()

Answer (score 1):

The warning that you're getting suggests that Vue in a Vitest environment struggles to determine whether `highcharts` is a native HTML element or a custom component.

I believe that a quick fix would be to change the component name from a single word (`<highcharts>`) to a name with `-` (like `<highcharts-chart>`). You can do this as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue#changing-global-component-tag-name):

```
app.use(HighchartsVue({ tagName: 'highcharts-chart' });
```

If this alone does not work, you can add an additional condition for custom components:

```
const app = createApp(App);
app.config.compilerOptions.isCustomElement = (tag) => tag.startsWith('my-custom-');
```

Alternatively, you could try importing the `Chart` component directly from `highcharts` instead of registering the `highcharts` component:

```
<script setup>
import { Chart } from 'highcharts';
</script>
<template>
  <Chart :options="{series:[{data:[1,2,3]}]}"></Chart>
</template>
```

When it comes to the second part of your question (how to access chart data), you can use `ref` to create add a reference to the Highcharts object and there, you have access to the entire `chart` instance.

```
<highcharts ref="chartRef" :options="options"></highcharts>
...
const chartRef = ref();
watch(chartRef, () => {
  const chart = chartRef.value.chart;
  console.log(chart); // open up the console to see what's available
});
```

**Demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-bas-rqqx93?file=/src/App.vue

**API:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart

Comment: and i have one more question, actually i published this component to using npm and vitest. i just added highcharts in external option in vitest,config.ts, should i also import highchart somewhere like main.ts or in my component ?

Comment: Hello, thanks for this greate answer, i understood exactly the reason of why i got a warn message from vue. by the way, i couldn't solve this error yet, when i put '-', there is another error appear, [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')] - main.ts and tag also it doesn't work. i'm also add Chart directly but it's not working.  Maybe, i registered globally this component using install.. i don't know

Comment: Hi, maybe try setting `HighchartsChart` instead of `highcharts-chart`? Also, would it be possible for you to reproduce this issue somewhere in a simple GitHub repository/online code editor so I could take a look and help you solve this problem?

Comment: Hi, i resolved this issue, i'm adding HighchartsVue in plugins global option when wrapper was created. thanks for your advice!!

Comment: great! I'm happy that you've solved it:)